# textArea.setText() wrong output

Tags: java, hashmap, textarea

I'm trying to print out a HashMap with keys and values into the TextArea field.
The map is printed when I try to print it out like this:

`for(Map.Entry<Integer,String> entry : kodovi.entrySet()) {
                        System.out.println(entry.getKey()+" : "+entry.getValue());}`

But when I try to print it out in a Text Area like this, it just prints out the last key and value.

```
for(Map.Entry<Integer,String> entry: kodovi.entrySet()){
    textArea.setText(entry.getKey()+" : "+entry.getValue());}
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time you call `textArea.setText(...)`,
the last call replaces whatever content was previously there.

You could get the previous content and append to it,
but string concatenation is inefficient.

It will be better to build a string using a `StringBuilder`,
and then set the content from that:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (Map.Entry<Integer, String> entry : kodovi.entrySet()) {
    sb.append(entry.getKey()).append(" : ").append(entry.getValue()).append("\n");
}

textArea.setText(sb.toString());
```